# how to apply salt states to just one environment

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to apply a salt state to my non prod environment at /srv/salt/non-prod
 I'm getting this result:

```
[root@salt non-prod]# salt '*' state.apply
salt.localdomain:
----------
          ID: states
    Function: no.None
      Result: False
     Comment: No Top file or external nodes data matches found.
     Changes:

Summary for salt.localdomain
------------
Succeeded: 0
Failed:    1
```

I have this location defined in my master config

```
   non-prod:
     - /srv/non-prod
     - /srv/salt/non-prod/services
     - /srv/salt/non-prod/states
```

I have a top file located here:

```
[root@salt ~]# cat /srv/salt/non-prod/top.sls
base:
  '*':
    - apache
    - python
    - ssh
    - users
```

These are the contents of the non-prod directory

```
  [root@salt ~]# ls -lh /srv/salt/non-prod/
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4.0K Oct  3 21:02 apache
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   45 Oct  3 20:57 python
drwxr-xr-x. 2 salt salt    6 Oct  3 14:10 services
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   54 Oct  3 18:23 ssh
drwxr-xr-x. 2 salt salt    6 Oct  3 14:10 states
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   80 Oct  3 15:29 state.template
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  174 Oct  3 15:30 test.sls
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   61 Oct  3 21:14 top.sls
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   22 Oct  3 21:03 users
drwxr-xr-x. 2 salt salt   99 Oct  3 18:28 webserver
```

it contains a few salt modules

How can I apply salt states to just the non-prod environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the syntax using some yaml validation tools, then we can go to next step.

Read [saltstack top](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/top.html) documentation thoroughly, you will notice setting different environment, you first explicitly define alternate environment `name` on /etc/salt/master and also specify it under top.sls

i.e., you file_roots specify the `non-prod` environment

```
file_roots:
  #non-prod environment
  non-prod:
    - /srv/non-prod
    - /srv/salt/non-prod/services
    - /srv/salt/non-prod/states
```

Thus your top.sls should use the environment name `non-prod` , not `base`

```
non-prod:
  '*':
    - apache
    - python
    - ssh
    - users
```

Since saltstack always use "base" environment by default, you should apply the state explicitly.

```
salt '*' state.highstate saltenv=non-prod
```

Comment: That works. But how I solved the problem was by setting the environment: non-prod variable in the /etc/salt/minion config. Restarting the minion service got this to work. I also tested your method and I got it working that way as well. Thanks!